# How to specify whether event listeners can be called or not depending on a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a variable which is assigned a value dependent on a value in a table in a db. How can I use this variable to specify whether certain event listeners are active and to specify whether particular links are shown.

For instance I have tried but did not successfully work:

```
    var accessLevel = 0;
    var userLoggedIn = "<?php Print($userLoggedIn); ?>";
    var userlevel = "<?php Print($userLevel); ?>";

    function map_initialize()
    {
        ////CONCERNING THIS PART#########///
        if (accessLevel >= 2){ //WHEN LOADED THIS IS NOT REGISTERING ANY RIGHT CLICK EVEN WHEN accessLevel is over 2!
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {

            //Some function that I don't want to run if accessLevel is <2

            });
           }
     }



    ////THIS WORKS FINE BELOW JUST PROVIDING IT
    if (userLoggedIn == true) {
        if (userlevel == "0") {
            accessLevel = 0;
            console.log(accessLevel);
        }    
        else if (userlevel == "1") {
            accessLevel = 1;
                        console.log(accessLevel);

        }
        else if (userlevel == "2"){
            accessLevel = 2;
                        console.log(accessLevel);

        }
        else if (userlevel == "3"){
            accessLevel = 3;
                        console.log(accessLevel);

        }
        else if (userlevel == "4"){
            accessLevel = 4;
                        console.log(accessLevel);

        }
    }
```

I don't know if this will make sense, but basically I want to be able filter certain available functions depending on what `accessLevel`'s value is. Is this possible (specifically to use with google maps elements as well), and how can I do it.

Comment: Please explain more. It is not clear with your statement. Do you see any error?

Comment: Please provide a **CLIENT-SIDE** version of your code -- where the PHP code has been executed.

Comment: @ApulGupta What I have above is incorrect syntax and is not even registering any click even if the `accessLevel` is above 2.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `)};` to `});` in the thirteenth line of the sample code.

Also change `userLoggedIn == true` to something like:

```
userLoggedIn.toLowerCase().trim() === "true"
```

**Assuming possible values of `$userLevel` are `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `true`, `false`.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, All I had to do was swap the location of the `if statement` so that it was within the click event listener as so.

```
function map_initialize()
{


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
            if (accessLevel >= 2){ 
                //Some function that I don't want to run if accessLevel is <2
            }
        });

 }
```